# Google Maps: Clustering with Fluster, hide markers and update clustering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using the Fluster library to do some clustering with the Google Maps API v3.
http://blog.fusonic.net/2009/12/fluster2-011-with-significant-performance-improvements/

I have "real-time" searching on the map. As you type in an input it hides or shows markers that match the search.

This works fine, however I can't get it to work with Fluster. i.e. I can show/hide my own markers, but I can't update the cluster markers.

Fluster doesn't seem to have a removeMarker() method. I tried adding my own, but with no luck...

```
this.removeMarker = function(_marker)
{
    var index = me.markers.indexOf(_marker);
    me.markers.splice(index, 1);
};
```

I would then try calling `fluster.createClusters()` or `fluster.zoomChanged()` but again, it just isn't doing what I want.

Does anyone know what I can do to work around this?

If it comes down to it, I guess I can remove the instant-search and just get it to re-render all the markers/clusters on the search form being submitted, but that is not an ideal solution.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.